# How to animate .olControlLayerSwitcher with Jquery?

Tags: openlayers-2, jquery, asp.net, openlayers

Not know much about css but some how got strucked in setting css property. I am using Openlayers .olControlLayerSwitcher class.  Here without using !important keyword, LayerSwitcher will not get move. Here is my code:

Its working.But very fast. I want to move it with some speed intervals like jquery animate.
Please suggest it.

```
$(".olControlLayerSwitcher").css("cssText", "top: 30px !important;"); 

$('.olControlLayerSwitcher').css("cssText", "top: 55px !important;");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, OpenLayers 3 doesn't have a LayerSwitcher control. In OpenLayers 2 however, there is a `.olControlLayerSwitcher` style which can be animated by JQuery without any further styling options. You can use JQuery's animate function for this task:

```
$(".olControlLayerSwitcher").animate({top: "55px"});
```

There is no need for the 30px animation, except if you want to see a break between the two animations. Then you have two options. You can use two animations or you can either call a callback function in the first animation.

First option:

```
$(".olControlLayerSwitcher").animate({top: "30px"});
$(".olControlLayerSwitcher").animate({top: "55px"});
```

Second option:

```
$(".olControlLayerSwitcher").animate({top: "30px"}, 400, function() {
    $(".olControlLayerSwitcher").animate({top: "55px"});
});
```

In the second option the 400 is the speed of he animation. You can set it to `"slow"`, `"fast"` or any value in milliseconds.

There is only one thing left. Somehow JQuery can't animate the `.olControlLayerSwitcher` style if the animation isn't called in the same function as the control. So if you put

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
```

in a function different then the JQuery animation the animation won't work. I can't figure out why this is happening, maybe someone smarter can answer this question.

Comment: Nice and very descriptive answer ;)